# What is my mistake when evaluating this limit?

Tags: limits

$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{x}=\infty$

But with l'Hospital's Rule

$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{0}{1}=0$

So where's my naive mistake?

Comment: l'Hopital's rule doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe l'Hopital's rule works only for indeterminate forms.

Comment: More precisely, $\lim_{x \to 0+} \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to 0+} \dfrac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ if

1) the limit on the right exists or is $+\infty$ or $-\infty$, and

2) Either $\lim_{x \to 0+} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0+} g(x) = 0$ or $\lim_{x \to 0+} g(x) = \pm \infty$.

Comment: Ah, of course.  How silly of me. :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

l'Hospital's Rule works on limits of the form "$\frac{0}{0}$" and "$\frac{\infty}{\infty}$" so you can not use it to evaluate your limit.

You can find the complete list of conditions you need to verify befote using l'Hospital's Rule [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)

Comment: Those conditions are not really complete.  The rule works if the limit of $g$ is $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ no matter what the limiting behaviour of $f$ is.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Wouldn't the above question be a counterexample to your claim? (Or, more likely, did I misunderstand what you meant?)

Comment: @MichaelBoratko: this is talking about a limit of $f/g$.  In the case at hand, $f = 1$ and $g = x$, and the limit of $g$ as $x \to 0$ is $0$, not $\infty$.  Or you could take $f = 1/x$ and $g = 1$, and the limit of $g$ as $x \to 0$ is $1$.

Comment: If you want to take $x \to \pm\infty$ with $f=1$ and $g=x$, the limit of $g$ is $\pm\infty$, so the rule should apply, and does:
$$\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} \frac{1}{x} = \lim_{x \to \pm \infty} \frac{0}{1} = 0$$

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes, my mistake. Thanks!